# Для чего нужны переменные счетчики

Tags: java, циклы, логические-выражения

Я только недавно натолкнулся на этот термин, и я не понимаю для чего они нужны и когда использовать.

Пример

```
int evenCount = 0; // количество четных чисел

int[] a = new int[10]; // массив из 10 элементов

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = new Random().nextInt(10); // инициализация массива случайными значениями от 0 до 9
    if (a[i] % 2 == 0) { // если число четное
        evenCount = evenCount + 1;
    }
}

System.out.println("количество четных чисел в массиве " + evenCount);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в приведённом вами примере кода всё и так объяснено. Переменная счётчик выполняет роль счётчика, который помогает подсчитать что-то в массиве/списке.

Comment: `evenCount = evenCount + 1` можно заменить на `evenCount++`

Comment: Эээ, сначала вопрос про переменные-флаги, теперь про переменные-счетчики. Вроде это понятия не настолько сложные, все же уже показано в примере.

Answer (score 1):

Часто требуется подсчитать, сколько раз во время вычислений наступает то или иное событие (выполняется то или иное условие).

Для этого вводится вспомогательная переменная, которой в начале присваивается нулевое значение, а после каждого наступления события она увеличивается на единицу.